# How to select all data from one column while the other columns has certain conditions?

Tags: mysql, select, conditional-statements

I have this table room_table with the headers

```
   +------------------------------------------------------------------------+
   |id|  day | startTime | endTime | room    | subject  | section | fullname|
   +------------------------------------------------------------------------+
   |1 |monday    | 7:00AM | 7:30AM    | NET LAB | Monday Subj      | 1ITG    |  John Doe|
   |2 |tuesday   | 7:30AM | 8:00AM    | NET LAB | Tuesday Subj     | 1ITG    |  John Doe|
   |3 |Wednesday | 3:00PM | 3:30PM    | NET LAB | Wednesday Subj   | 1ITG    |  John Doe|
   |4 |Thursday  | 4:30PM | 5:00PM    | NET LAB | Thursday Subj    | 1ITG    |  John Doe|
   |5 |Friday    | 7:00PM | 7:30PM    | NET LAB | Friday Subj      | 1ITG    |  John Doe|
   |6 |Saturday  | 8:30PM | 9:00PM    | NET LAB | Saturday Subject | 1ITG    |  John Doe|
```

How can I display it in php like this? A table with the time header and all the school days with corresponding subject with the specific time span. I always get error in formulating nested select statements.

```
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|   TIME   |  MONDAY  |  TUESDAY   |    WEDNESDAY | THURSDAY |FRIDAY|SATURDAY|
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|7:00-7:30| Monday Subj |            |              |              |           |                |
|7:30-8:00|             |Tuesday Subj|              |              |           |                |
|8:00-8:30|             |            |              |              |           |                |
|8:30-9:00|             |            |              |              |           |                |
|9:00-9:30|             |            |              |              |           |                |
|9:30-10:00|            |            |              |              |           |                |
|10:00-10:30|           |            |              |              |           |                |
|10:30-11:00|           |            |              |              |           |                |
|11:00-11:30|           |            |              |              |           |                |
|11:30-12:00|           |            |              |              |           |                |
|12:00-12:30|           |            |              |              |           |                |
|12:30-1:00|            |            |              |              |           |                |
|1:00-1:30|         |            |              |              |           |                |
|1:30-2:00|         |            |              |              |           |                |
|2:00-2:30|             |            |              |              |           |                |
|2:30-3:00|         |            |Wednesday Subj|              |           |                |
|3:00-3:30|         |            |              |              |           |                |
|3:30-4:00|         |            |              |              |           |                |
|4:00-4:30|         |            |              |              |           |                |
|4:30-5:00|         |            |              |Thursday Subj |           |                |
|5:00-5:30|         |            |              |              |           |                |
|5:30-6:00|         |            |              |              |           |                |
|6:00-6:30|         |            |              |              |           |                |
|6:30-7:00|         |            |              |              |           |                |
|7:00-7:30|         |            |              |              |Friday Subj|                |
|7:30-8:00|         |            |              |              |           |                |
|8:00-8:30|             |            |              |              |           |                |
|8:30-9:00|         |            |              |              |           |Saturday Subject|
```

I have this query but it only outputs the time with subjects. How can I change this to display the all the time even if there is no corresponding subjects with the certain time?

```
    SELECT time_format(startTime, '%h:%i%p') as newStart, 
    time_format(endTime, '%h:%i%p') as newEnd,
    max(case when day = 'Monday' then subject else null end) monday,
    max(case when day = 'Tuesday' then subject else null end) tuesday,
    max(case when day = 'Wednesday' then subject else null end) wednesday,
    max(case when day = 'Thursday' then subject else null end) thursday,
    max(case when day = 'Friday' then subject else null end) friday,
    max(case when day = 'Saturday' then subject else null end) saturday
    from table where section='1ITG' group by newStart,newEnd
```

Comment: "How can I change this to display the all the time even if there is no corresponding subjects with the certain time?" What are all the times?

Comment: Probably, you don't want to apply any conditions then? A condition always matches a full row

Comment: Consider handling issues of data display in application code

Comment: I think by `all the time`, OP meant `time slots`. For example, on `Monday`, there's a subject or lecture assigned to time slot `7:00-7:30` and the remaining slots are empty. OP wants the remaining slots to be printed too even if they have no subjects assigned. And this should be done for all the days.

Comment: @MathewsMathai exactly. Is it possible?

Comment: It's possible. It's just not a brilliant idea.

Comment: I guess it's possible but I have no idea how to get it done. I am only used to basic queries. :( It scares me even more because you have 2 separate columns `startTime` and `endTime` and you need them combined in result. I have no idea how to go about that.

Comment: @Strawberry how come it's not a brilliant one?

Comment: Because this kind of thing is best handled in the presentation layer.

Comment: Essentially, `SELECT * FROM room_table ORDER BY id;` is all the query you need. Everything else can and should be handled in PHP.